# Respond to "dialog:afterclose" once

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to respond to `dialog:afterclose` only once, and I'm not having any luck getting the syntax right (and I'm having trouble finding resources because most search results refer to jquery.once, which has been removed). Here's my best guess:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MyCustomModule = {
    attach(context) {
      const $window = $(once('MyCustomModule', window, context));
      $window.on('dialog:afterclose', (e) => {
        console.log('closed');
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

That never fires. If I change `$window` to `$(window)` it fires, but eight times. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal behaviors are triggered once after `DOMContentLoaded` with `document` context, but AFAIK never in the `window` context. Also, in a global use-case like this, you do not want to limit your once-function with a `context`, because if your behavior is loaded later and not with the initial load, the `document` will never again be part of the `context` again and therefore will never match again.

So the solution should be simply changing your once element from window to document, without context:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MyCustomModule = {
    attach(context) {
      const elements = once('MyCustomModule', document);
      elements.forEach( () => {
        $(window).doSomething();
      });
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Hudri, particularly the information re: context. When I try the revised code you've provided unchanged, for some reason the forEach() loop never runs, and nothing inside of it ever happens—maybe document is a special element that's treated differently. If I replace document with 'html' the loop runs, but my calls to $(window).on('dialog:afterclose') still fire twice for some reason. I'll keep testing and see what I can come up with.